# PySide6 Change QSqlTable/QTableView to display as numeric instead of Scientific notation

Tags: python, qtableview, pyside6

GUI made with QTDesigner displays all values > 1million as scientific notation. Attached some parts of the code. The whole program is rather long and split into multiple files. The query is built in a function and returned as "query"
Qquery is converting it to be the type of input that QtSql wants for .setQuery.

```
        Qquery = QtSql.QSqlQuery(query)
    
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self, self.datab)
        self.model.setQuery(Qquery)
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.model.submitAll()

        widgets.SQLTable.setModel(self.model)
        widgets.SQLTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Part of the Query is shown below. The two columns I have that are large numbers are Input + Output. I have tried casting input as varchar to make it read in the table as a string, but I think the QTableView still sees it as a number because it is still converted into scientific notation.

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT "
SQLQuery = SQLQuery + "      tb_EQUIPMENT_NAME_DEF.EQUIPMENT_NAME"

if ShiftSplit:
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery + "      ,SHIFT"

SQLQuery = SQLQuery + "      ,[EVENT1_ID] AS 'ROUTE'"
SQLQuery = SQLQuery + "      ,CAST(SUM([INPUT]) AS varchar(50)) AS INPUT"
SQLQuery = SQLQuery + "      ,SUM([OUTPUT]) AS OUTPUT"
```

SQLTable is the name of the QTableView object in the gui, the query is ran and the data from the model pumped into the table. What I am looking for is a way to make it display in the GUI without scientific notation. As the data is in the model, and goes directly to the table, I don't see a good way of trying to do it with a type conversion inside of my current code, and trying to do the conversion inside of the SQL Query didn't make any difference.

[image: GUI]

Comment: You have to use a delegate. You could just override [`displayText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#displayText) and return an appropriate string formatting whenever the value is numeric.

Comment: @musicamante I ended up using display role from some examples found. Posted solution based on other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Found some examples online, made a subclass with Qt.DisplayRole to fix it:

```
class SQLModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(SQLModel, self).__init__(parent)

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if not index.isValid():
        return QVariant()

    #column = index.column()
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:            
        #if column == 2:
        value = QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, index)
        if isinstance(value, float):
    # Render float to 0 dp
            return "%.0f" % value

        if isinstance(value, int):
    # Render float to 0 dp
            return "%.0f" % value

    return QtSql.QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)
```

Didn't need decimals anywhere so changed float format to 0 decimal places.
Replaced the model assignment to call the class:

```
        #self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self, self.datab)
        self.model = SQLModel(self)
```

Comment: Note that the display role shouldn't "alter" the value of the model: the purpose of that role is to provide the view a content that is "to be rendered in the form of text"; it's responsibility of the view (or, better, its delegate) to *actually* display that text, eventually deciding how to "render" it. That's why you should use a delegate instead. Besides, your code above makes a pointless distinction: just do `if isinstance(value, (int, float)): return "%.0f" % value`